Converting timestamped values into value in a range
So I have a data like:



TimeStamp
Value




ts1
10


ts2
20


ts3
20


ts4
30


ts5
40


ts6
40


ts7
10



I want to change it to depict for how long a value sustained
For eg, for the above table the output would be



startTime(Inclusive)
endtime (Exclusive)
Value




ts1
ts2
10


ts2
ts4
20


ts4
ts5
30


ts5
ts7
40


ts7
null
10




Note: Assume unique TimeStamps & Increasing in nature.


Which dbms are you using?

What have you tried and what exactly do you need to know?


Identify groups of same continues values. Note the row_number subtraction is necessary (google for "gaps and islands"), plain partition by value would be wrong since values repeat in different groups.
Choose first (the oldest) row of all group.
The start time is obvious, end time is the start time of next group hence the lead window function. (If you required end time inclusive, the solution would be much simpler using group by+min+max.)

with t(TimeStamp,   Value) as (values
  ('ts1',   10),
  ('ts2',   20),
  ('ts3',   20),
  ('ts4',   30),
  ('ts5',   40),
  ('ts6',   40),
  ('ts7',   10)
)
,
groups as (
  select t.*
       , row_number() over (order by t.timestamp) - row_number() over (partition by t.value order by t.timestamp) as grp
  from t
)
--select * from groups order by timestamp
,
occurences as (
  select g.timestamp
       , g.value
       , row_number() over (partition by g.grp order by g.timestamp) as rn
  from groups g
)
,
first_occurences as (
  select o.timestamp, o.value
  from occurences o
  where o.rn = 1
)
select fo.timestamp as start_time_inclusive
     , lead(fo.timestamp) over (order by fo.timestamp) as end_time_exclusive
     , fo.value
from first_occurences fo
order by fo.timestamp





start_time_inclusive
end_time_exclusive
value




ts1
ts2
10


ts2
ts4
20


ts4
ts5
30


ts5
ts7
40


ts7
null
10




SELECT 5


fiddle

See example
with t as(
  select *,sum(ch)over(order by TimeStamp) gr  -- change num - group number
  from(
    select * 
      ,case when value=lag(value,1,value)over(order by TimeStamp) then 0 
       else 1  -- value changed
       end ch  
    from myData
  )a
)
select min(TimeStamp) start_time_inclusive
  ,lead(min(TimeStamp),1,min(TimeStamp))over(order by min(TimeStamp))end_time_exclusive
  ,min(value) value
from t
group by gr


You have a gaps and islands problem, you could use the difference between two row_numbers to give a unique id to each successive group of rows, with same Value, Then we can use window function lead(), to get the end time which is the next start time
Assuming you are using a DBMS that supports window functions :
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by TimeStamp )
         - row_number() over (partition by Value order by TimeStamp ) as grp
  from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select min(TimeStamp) as min_ts, max(TimeStamp) as max_ts, Value
  from cte
  group by Value, grp
)
select min_ts as startTime, 
       lead(min_ts) over (order by min_ts) as endtime,
       Value
from cte2
order by min_ts;

Results :
startTime   endtime Value
ts1         ts2     10
ts2         ts4     20
ts4         ts5     30
ts5         ts7     40
ts7         null    10

Demo here
